# nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

Tags: spring, apache-commons-dbcp, spring-mybatis

when i try to connection to database,there are some exceptions

here are my spring-mybatis configration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbc.initialSize}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="${jdbc.maxActive}"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${jdbc.maxIdle}"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="${jdbc.minIdle}"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="${jdbc.maxWait}"/>
</bean>
```

and here are my mybatis-config:

```
<settings>
    <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="true"/>
    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
    <setting name="aggressiveLazyLoading" value="true"/>
    <setting name="multipleResultSetsEnabled" value="true"/>
    <setting name="useColumnLabel" value="true"/>
    <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="true"/>
    <setting name="autoMappingBehavior" value="PARTIAL"/>
    <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="SIMPLE"/>
</settings>
```

`Type` Exception Report

`Message` Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

`Description` The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

there is exception:
    Exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server.)
### The error may exist in file [D:\Java\WeChat-API-lifecat\target\WeChat-API-lifecat\WEB-INF\classes\mapper\UserMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.kevinten.wechat.mapper.UserMapper.queryUserList
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server.)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
Root Cause

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server.)
### The error may exist in file [D:\Java\WeChat-API-lifecat\target\WeChat-API-lifecat\WEB-INF\classes\mapper\UserMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.kevinten.wechat.mapper.UserMapper.queryUserList
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server.)
    org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:77)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.selectList(Unknown Source)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:230)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:119)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:63)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.queryUserList(Unknown Source)
    com.kevinten.wechat.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.getUserList(UserServiceImpl.java:23)
    com.kevinten.wechat.controller.UserController.getUserList(UserController.java:25)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
Root Cause

org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server.)
### The error may exist in file [D:\Java\WeChat-API-lifecat\target\WeChat-API-lifecat\WEB-INF\classes\mapper\UserMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.kevinten.wechat.mapper.UserMapper.queryUserList
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
```

Answer (score 1):

the error clarify that **Could not create connection to database server**,  so please check the database url, username, password etc...